# Retrieve node from firebase without subnode

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

My app will display the offers for the user, and he can pick one and press join, which will send the email account to "Joiners" node.

But now my problem is I want him to see how many people have joined by counting "Joiners" node, without downloading all the emails that inside, of course.

**So what I want again:**

1. Retrieve "1231qq" Node without the Emails that in "Joiners" Node.
2. Count how many email that in "Joiners" node but without having to
   make the user download the whole node with other user's emails

I don't know exactly if I'm missing a technology that Firebase offer to do that kind of registration or what, so I would love some advice here, and thank you for your efforts.

[image: Firebase snapchat]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database SDKs always load entire branches of the JSON. There is no way to get only a part of a node.

When you are looking for something like this, it typically means you need to heed the recommendation in the Firebase documentation to [never nest multiple entity types under a single node](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#avoid_nesting_data). For example, you'll want to split the data in your screenshot over two top-level nodes like this:

```
Offers: {
  "1231qq": {
    done: 1231,
    name: "...",
    required: 3000,
    url: "..."
  }
},
OfferJoiners: {
  "1231qq": {
    1: "Email 1",
    2: "Email 2"
  }
}
```

With the above structure, you can load just the offer details without the joiner from `Offers`. And when needed, you perform a second call to also load that offers joiners from `OfferJoiners`. The extra call does not cause as much overhead as you may think, since [Firebase pipelines the requests over a single connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786).

Comment: I totally agree with you about multiple entity types under a single node. That fix the problem but perhaps maybe I didn't explain enough because I just don't feel it's efficient that just to count how many joiners I have, I have to download the whole node to the user even if its not overhead or really fast.



I just preferred to keep those emails as private as it could be, because I don't want to retrieve them in first place. 



I thought about creating an int value in offer, so I can use transaction to increment this value with each join, would that be a good practice?

Comment: If you only care about the count of the joiners, that would be a good starting point. But then how do you ensure that everyone can only join once (if that is a concern for your use-case)?

Comment: Can't think of a way to do that, to be honest. It looks like I have to retrieve the whole node just to make sure that the user can only join once.

Comment: Well, that depends. An array is typically not the right structure to guarantee uniqueness, because it can by definition contain duplicate items. I recommend switching to a map (`{ "user@domain,com": true, "user2@domain,com": true }` to ensure uniqueness. Note the `,` instead of a `.` in there, as keys can't contain dots (and conveniently: email addresses can't contain a comma). I recommend also checking some of these, as we covered uniqueness a few times before and that might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase-realtime-database%5d%20unique%20value

Comment: That definitely would do. Thanks a lot for helping.